# Priority channel with MessageStore and custom comparator

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have a channel witch collects messages in h2 DB:

.channel(MessageChannels.priority("jdbcChannel", jdbcChannelMessageStore(),"jdbc").capacity(5))

I need to add custom Comparator, to prioritize, witch messages to poll first.

I did like this:

.channel(MessageChannels.priority("jdbcChannel", jdbcChannelMessageStore(),"jdbc").capacity(5).comparator(comparator))

But I got an error: Only one of 'comparator' or 'messageGroupStore' can be specified.

What is this? I can add comparator only to channel without jdbc mode? And what if I need to use jdbc and comparator together?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. You cannot. The persistent store has a limitation for the priority functionality only via specific `MESSAGE_PRIORITY` column. The persistent implementation cannot do any custom comparison since there is no way to propagate it down to the store. For JDBC, for example, we do this on `PriorityChannel`:

```
public String getPriorityPollFromGroupQuery() {
    return SELECT_COMMON +
            "order by MESSAGE_PRIORITY DESC NULLS LAST, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_SEQUENCE LIMIT 1";
}
```

So, we sort messages in the store by that `MESSAGE_PRIORITY` and return only one, top record.

Does it make sense for you?

You may provide your own `H2ChannelMessageStoreQueryProvider` implementation, though, but again: Java `Comparator` is not going to be send down do DB.